# How to modify an existing Shopware 6 rule and persist the changes?

Tags: javascript, php, rules, persist, shopware

I'm using Shopware 6 and I've modified one the existing **LineItemsInCartCountRule** to match my specific needs (I don't need the stock functionality). However, when updating to a newer Shopware version my changes will be overwritten - is there a specific way to persist my custom code across Shopware updates?

Answer (score 0):

You should never edit the code directly. You should always to do it with a Decoration or Event.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html